# Is there a term for noises which CAN'T be written as normal text?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, etymology, dictionaries

Hard to give examples, as if I'm able to do it, I won't be asking this, but consider some sounds made by the tongue.

I'm giving examples of sounds which CAN be written to give you an idea:
Dog growling - Grrrrr
Sneezing - Aaccchhhhoooo

I need a word for sounds which can't be written.

Comment: You could check in OED for 'vocalisable' then add the prefix non- if it's there. But that would only give you a dodgy premodifier.

Comment: Please describe some of the sounds - e.g. *the sound of cards being shuffled* rather than the onomatopoeic *shoop shoop* or *trrr*.